# Postgres regex substring or regexp_matches

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to figure the following for a past days.

table1: synonym

```
Id         Synonym       code

------------------------------
1          Car Tyre      001

2          Bike Tyre     002

3          Cycle Tyre    003

4          Hammer Tube   001
```

Now My input = 'WITH CAR TYRE FROM Hammer Tube AUDI 2000'

Output = List code '001' for two times because input text contains both 'CAR TYRE' and 'Hammer Tube'

When i try this below query it shows only one time but i need twice

```
Select * from synonym where 'WITH CAR TYRE FROM Hammer Tube AUDI 2000' ~ Synonym;
```

Comment: CAR TYRE is in upper case. Are you sure it would give you two result.

Comment: Case is not an issue, if its is lower case also no problem but i need twice in result. please help me.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html , Read 9.7.3. then you will get more information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position()` in combination with `lower()`:

```
with synonym(id, synonym, code) as (
values
    (1, 'Car Tyre', '001'),
    (2, 'Bike Tyre', '002'),
    (3, 'Cycle Tyre', '003'),
    (4, 'Hammer Tube', '001')
)

select *
from synonym
where position(lower(synonym) in lower('WITH CAR TYRE FROM Hammer Tube AUDI 2000')) > 0

 id |   synonym   | code 
----+-------------+------
  1 | Car Tyre    | 001
  4 | Hammer Tube | 001
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you its working perfectly,  in this scenario now i need unique rows with count..